# PHP error 500 when including a left join on a pager query in db_select()

Tags: database, wsod

I've got a query which is causing a PHP error 500 whenever I add a left join:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function orderBy() on a non-object

Here's the query:

```
$query = db_select('my_table', 'mt')
         ->extend('PagerDefault')
         ->fields('mt')
         ->fields('u', array('name')
         ->leftJoin('users', 'u', 'u.uid = mt.user_id')
         ->orderBy('mt.my_table_id', 'DESC')
         ->limit($results_per_page);

$result = $query->execute();
```

The query is to be used with a table + pager. If I remove the `jeftJoin()` and respective `fields()` the query works perfectly. Can anyone shed some light as to why this might be happening?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Joins cannot be chained, so they have to be called separately (see Chaining). If you are chaining multiple functions together do it like this:
>
> ```
> $query = db_select('node', 'n');
> $query->join('field_data_body', 'b', 'n.nid = b.entity_id');
> $query
>   ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
>   ->condition('n.type', 'page')
>   ->condition('n.status', '1')
>   ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')
>   ->addTag('node_access');
> ```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - I didn't realise you can't chain joins. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: As a side note on this, the pager query must be added before the join: https://drupal.org/node/1298070#comment-5068720